# origin of idiom "small dice"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiom-meaning, phrase-origin

I've been using an idiom ambiguously: "That's **small dice**."

1. Does this refer to unfavorable outcomes in [games of
   chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps)? (equivalent to "chump
   change", like "those are small dice"?). See also "[no dice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_dice)", which has origins in craps.
2. Or rather, is the idiom a reference to [diced food](https://www.uwhealth.org/healthfacts/neuro/459.pdf)? (equivalent to "overly scrupulous"?)

Example usage.

- *Sorry if this seems like **small dice**, but I've double booked Wednesday evenings...*
- *Also one time she accidentally tripped me in capture the flag, but that's **small dice** compared...(weird expression... small dice, what does that even mean?)... [sic] to this one time, we were on a bus going to a music contest for my orchestra, and some of the other people in orchestra dared her to call me "sexy".*
  http://armorgames.com/community/thread/8027776/the-rant-thread

Comment: You didn't link to any examples of "small dice". In any case, it does not appear to be a common idiom at all, as I only get [~4 Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q="that%27s+small+dice"), with the earliest being from 2011.

Comment: I see. 2 examples: 1. [no dice](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic39942.html) as in "Can you lend me ten dollars? Sorry, no dice." 2. "Sorry if this seems like **small dice,** but I've double booked Wednesday evenings..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom I know of is '**small potatoes**'.

Perhaps yours is a local adaptation. I get nothing on it, personally, except the NGram (see below).

> small potatoes : something or someone insignificant; small fry. This contract is small potatoes, but it keeps us in business till we get into the real money. Small potatoes are better than no potatoes at all.

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/small+potatoes).

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small+dice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmall%20dice%3B%2Cc0) returns a result for '**small dice**' however, falling to 1960, then coming back up to 2000.

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small+potatoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmall%20potatoes%3B%2Cc0) for small potatoes shows a stronger result.